# What is the name of this shape? (two arcs and two tangents)

Tags: terminology, geometry

Think the shape of a two-pulley belt or a fully tightened bicycle chain:

[image: Pulley Belt]

If it was symmetrical, it could be called rounded rectangle, but not when the radii are not equal.

Comment: ...rounded trapezoid? (I have absolutely no idea, just guessing)

Comment: that might be it (also the trapezoid has to be isosceles), go ahead and make it an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rounded Trapezoid. Is this good enough?